# Объясните работу функции, пожалуйста!

Tags: javascript, функции

```
var arr = ['bla','hahahah','123456789','1','ew'];

function lensort(a,b)
{

    var s1 = "" + a; // Что это за переменная?
    var s2 = "" + b; // а это?
    if(s1.length < s2.lenght){
        return false;  
    } 
    else if(s1.length > s2.length){
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
console.log(arr.sort(lensort)) --> arr["1", "ew", "bla", "hahahah", "123456789"]
```

как эта функция отсортировала массив по длине его элементов?

Comment: [mdn: sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 1):

Как описан Grundy, тут основной момент играет использование метода `sort`. По сути, функция `lensort` представляет собой "критерий выбора". Т.е. метод `sort` отдает методу `lensort` 2 значения. Т.е. на первом шаге оно выдало в метод `lensort` значения `arr[0]` и `arr[1] ( 'bla','hahahah')`. Далее помечу в коде что и как:

```
 function lensort(a,b)
 {
    var s1 = "" + a; // Это первый параметр или arr[0]
    var s2 = "" + b; // это второй параметр или arr[1]
    // по сути тут мы однозначно получаем строки s1 и s2 типа string 
    if(s1.length < s2.lenght){
        return false;  // элементы на своих позициях по возрастанию
    } 
    else if(s1.length > s2.length){
        return true; // элемент arr[0] больше и его мы будет "двигать" вправо по массиву
    }
}
```

В итоге, когда ваша функция `lensort` возвращает `true`, то метод `sort` делает решение что первый элемент "больше" второго и смешает его правее. И дальше итерация перемещается дальше и сравнивает другие 2 значения, например `arr[1]` и `arr[2]` (в зависимости от алгоритма, могут сравниваться первый элемент со всеми оставльными, или методом пузырька и т.п. смотрите "алгоритмы сортировки")

Answer (score 0):

```
var s1 = "" + a;
```

так делают чтобы получить строку в любом случае, то есть если там будет *123456789* то оно может быть как string так и int, чтобы оно однозначно имело тип string делают такую хитрую операцию, таких хитростей много, например если мы хотим иметь всегда какое-то значение то делаем так

```
var s = object.param || "строка";
```

и тогда даже если string будет **object.param** не будет существовать в переменной **s** будет значение *"строка"* ,а не undefined.

Comment: `'123456789'` - Это **всегда** строка